# Querying SCCM Server to get ADD/Remove Programs list of a specific computer

Tags: sccm, vbscript, query

First of all, i'm sorry for my english.
I'm new in vbs scripting and wmi queries and I need your help.

My goal is to get the Add/Remove Programs list of a specific computer.
I saw many scripts which query the Uninstall registry key on the target computer but I want to do it even if the computer is offline. That's why i'm querying the SCCM Server.

My query seems to be good because when i put it in Report Builder, it returns a good result.

Here is the query :

```
Select sys.Name0,adv.DisplayName0 FROM v_R_System sys , v_Add_Remove_Programs adv where sys.ResourceID=adv.ResourceID and sys.Name0 like '%XXXXXXXX%'
```

My problem is to get the result of the query using vbscript. I'm getting an error on the line of the "For Each"

Here is my script :

```
'Central SCCM Site Server name
strComputer = "SCCM_SERVER"

'Central SCCM Site Code
strSiteCode = "DC1"

'Set up the connection String
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts://" & strComputer & "\root\sms\site_" & strSiteCode)




'Get the info with a query
Set colGroups = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select sys.Name0,adv.DisplayName0 FROM v_R_System sys , v_Add_Remove_Programs adv where sys.ResourceID=adv.ResourceID and sys.Name0 like 'XXXXXXXXXXX'")


'output the info
For Each objGroup in colGroups
    Wscript.echo objGroup.DisplayName0 & " - "
Next
```

Can you please provide me some help ?

Update : it seems that i'm not using the right language for the query. I'm using SQL instead of WQL.

I don't know how to translate my query into WQL.
Can you help please ?

Comment: Eww, vbs.  Use PowerShell instead, it sucks much less.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a SQL query to get results from CM07/CM12. You need to use WQL to query CM07/CM12. Translate your query to WQL and it should work or rewrite your VBS to query SQL directly.